# Why do we need a tangent space? Why do we need a vector field? ("Calculus on Manifolds" by MIchael Spivak)

Tags: vector-fields, tangent-spaces

I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

Why do we need a tangent space?
Why do we need a vector field?

> To be precise, a vector field is a function $F$ such that $F(p)\in\mathbb{R}_p^n$ for each $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$. For each $p$ there are numbers $F^1(p),\dots,F^n(p)$ such that $$F(p)=F^1(p)\cdot (e_1)_p+\cdots + F^n(p)\cdot (e_n)_p.$$

I think the following definition is sufficient.

> A vector field is a function $F$ such that $F(p)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ for each $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

If we want to know a vector at $p$, we just need to calculate $F(p)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

In fact, in introductory electromagnetism textbooks, the definition of tangent space is not provided.

Comment: Maybe you do not need tangent spaces, vector fields; maybe you do not need manifolds, topology, etc. It depends on what you are planning to study. The fact that some elementary physics books do not contain any (mildly) advanced math concepts is not all that surprising (after all, Maxwell did not know what a manifold is).

Comment: It may be worth emphasizing that the ordinary sense of scalar/vector fields in electromagnetism are simply scalar/vector-valued functions. (Hence the initial Wikipedia definition: "In vector calculus and physics, a vector field is an assignment of a vector to each point in a space, most commonly Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.)  There's certainly treatments of electromagnetism which use the definition for manifolds but it's not the baseline approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need a tangent space because we're trying to do calculus on manifolds, which means we want to do calculus without preferring a particular coordinate chart.    When generalizing vector calculus on $\mathbb{R}^3$, many concepts that were identified become distinct.   Vectors in the sense of the derivative of a path, and vectors in the sense of a gradient of a scalar function become tangent vectors and covectors.   Vectors at one point are no longer directly comparable to vectors at another point, so we need a tangent space at each point.

Comment: Lawrence D'Anna, thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to think of your differentiable manifold (I'll call it $ M $) concretely as a $ 2 $-dimensional surface embedded in $ \mathbb R ^ 3 $.  (This is the sort of manifold that the pioneers of the field first studied, after all.)  So you have a point $ p $ on this surface $ M $, and you can see that some of the vectors (in the ordinary sense of elements of $ \mathbb R ^ 3 $) are tangent to $ M $ at $ p $, while others are normal (perpendicular), and most are neither (while the zero vector is technically both).  An $ \mathbb R ^ 3 $-valued field on $ M $ maps each point $ p $ to an element of $ \mathbb R ^ 3 $, but a *tangent* vector field is specifically one that maps each point $ p $ to a vector that's tangent to $ M $ at $ p $.

The vectors that are tangent at $ p $ form a $ 2 $-dimensional subspace of $ \mathbb R ^ 3 $, which you can write as $ \mathrm T _ p M $ and call the tangent space to $ M $ at $ p $.  (The normal vectors form a $ 1 $-dimensional subspace $ \mathrm N _ p M $, and $ \mathrm T _ p M $ and $ \mathrm N _ p M $ together span $ \mathbb R ^ 3 $.)  Since this is a $ 2 $-dimensional vector space, we could assign it a basis and identify it with $ \mathbb R ^ 2 $, and I gather that this is what Spivak is doing when he writes $ \mathbb R ^ 2 _ p $.  But even in this concrete setting where $ M $ is a submanifold of $ \mathbb R ^ 3 $, there's no canonical way to do this.  (At best, there are $ { 3 \choose 2 } = 3 $ canonical ways, each given by picking $ 2 $ of the $ 3 $ coordinates of $ \mathbb R ^ 3 $.  At any given point on the manifold $ M $, at least one of these must work, but it's possible that none of them will work everywhere on $ M $, and guaranteed that none of them will work everywhere if $ M $ is closed.  Even so, it's useful to be able to use any basis.)

When we make $ M $ an abstract manifold, we keep the terminology ‘tangent vector’, but we can no longer think of these as vectors in some ambient space $ \mathbb R ^ N $.  (The Whitney embedding theorem tells us that it must be possible to embed $ M $ into some $ \mathbb R ^ N $, at least as long as $ M $ is paracompact as it usually is in practice, but there's still no canonical way to do this.)  So instead we can think of tangent vectors at $ p $ as derivations of smooth or differentiable functions defined on $ M $ near $ p $, as equivalence classes of smooth or differentiable curves in $ M $ through $ p $, or as compatible ways to assign elements of $ \mathbb R ^ n $ to smooth or differentiable coordinate charts on $ M $ around $ p $.  This makes the whole concept more abstract, but its origins are the vectors tangent to a surface in $ \mathbb R ^ 3 $.

Comment: Toby Bartels, thank you very much for your detailed answer.